# One form used on multiple page with one controller action

Tags: forms, symfony, optimization, controller

I'm working with Symfony 3 and I have an "optimisation" issue :

- I have ONE form
- This form is used in ONE controller
- But this form is used in TWO pages

Is it possible to create the view + handle the user's anwser for this form ONE time for the TWO pages?

Right now the only solution I see is to duplicate my code TWO times for each pages (= TWO actions in my Controller)

Any advice?

```
**
* @Route("/blabla")
*/
class MonController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/blabla")
 *
 * some stuff
 */
public function homePageAction(Entity $entity, Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(DateType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data  = $form->getData();

        dump($data);
    }

    return $this->render(':directory:file.html.twig', [
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'      => $form->createView()
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/blabla")
 *
 * some stuff
 *
 */
public function detailAction(Entity $entity)
{
      // I need to do the same here to show and handle my form         

      return $this->render('mon template');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code? We use the same controller methods for multiple pages and actions at work all the time.

Comment: @ASOlivieri Well, right now I didn't handle the form in my Controller, I wanted to think about a better solution before ! If I find how post my code I will try (I'm new here, sorry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution set up by the main Dev was to create a service to handle the form "solution" (a zodiac sign) and do this in the Controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/{slugHoroscope}", name="horoscope_homepage")
 *
 * @ParamConverter("horoscope", class="AppBundle:Horoscope", options={
 *    "mapping": {"slugHoroscope": "slug"},
 *    "repository_method" = "findByComplexSlug",
 *    "map_method_signature" = true
 * })
 */
public function homePageAction(Horoscope $horoscope, $slugHoroscope, ZodiacService $zodiacService, Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(DateType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $date = $form->get('date')->getData();

        $parameters = [
            'slugHoroscope' => $slugHoroscope,
            'slugZodiac'    => $zodiacService->getSignByDate($date)->getSlug(),
        ];

        return $this->redirectToRoute('horoscope_detail', $parameters);
    }

    return $this->render(':horoscope:acc-horoscope.html.twig', [
        'horoscope' => $horoscope,
        'form'      => $form->createView()
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/{slugHoroscope}/{slugZodiac}.{_format}", name="horoscope_detail", defaults={"_format": "html"})
 *
 * @ParamConverter("horoscopeSigne", class="AppBundle:HoroscopeSigne", options={
 *    "mapping": {"slugHoroscope": "slugHoroscope", "slugZodiac": "slugZodiac"},
 *    "repository_method" = "findByComplexSlug",
 *    "map_method_signature" = true
 * })
 */
public function detailAction(HoroscopeSigne $horoscopeSigne, $slugHoroscope, Request $request)
{
    $horoscope = $horoscopeSigne->getHoroscope();

    $form = $this->createForm(DateType::class, null, [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('horoscope_homepage', ['slugHoroscope' => $slugHoroscope])
    ]);

    $template = $horoscopeSigne
        ->getHoroscope()
        ->getHoroscopeModele()
        ->getTemplatePath();

    return $this->render('horoscope/'.$template, [
        'horoscope'      => $horoscope,
        'horoscopeSigne' => $horoscopeSigne,
        'form'           => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So you can put both routes to one method. Your annotations would be combined and be something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{slugHoroscope}", name="horoscope_homepage")
 * @Route("/{slugHoroscope}/{slugZodiac}.{_format}", name="horoscope_detail", defaults={"_format": "html"})
```

Put your params in the same annotation.

Then add params to whichever method you're going to use. So something like this:

```
public function homePageAction(Horoscope $horoscope = null, HoroscopeSigne $horoscopeSigne = null, Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(DateType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data  = $form->getData();

        dump($data);
    }
}
```

Then you're going to have to do some logic on the route and params. Something like:

```
$request = $this->container->get('request');
$routeName = $request->get('_route');

if ($routeName == 'horoscope_homepage) {
   $template = the_template_for_the_homepage;
   $params = the_parameters_for_the_homepage;
} else {
   $template = the_template_for_the_other_page;
   $params = the_params_for_the_other_page;
}
```

Then you'll also have to do some logic on the params. Something like:

```
if ($horoscope == null) {
   //your logic
}
```

Then return your template and params. Like this:

```
return $this->render($template, $params);
```

You're going to have to fiddle with a lot of logic. Another option is to extract your form logic to another method or service.

As in:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use...

**
* @Route("/horoscopes")
*/
class HoroscopeController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/{slugHoroscope}", name="horoscope_homepage")
 *
 * @ParamConverter("horoscope", class="AppBundle:Horoscope", options={
 *    "mapping": {"slugHoroscope": "slug"},
 *    "repository_method" = "findByComplexSlug",
 *    "map_method_signature" = true
 * })
 */
public function homePageAction(Horoscope $horoscope, Request $request)
{
    $this->formMethod();

    return $this->render(':horoscope:acc-horoscope.html.twig', [
        'horoscope' => $horoscope,
        'form'      => $form->createView()
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/{slugHoroscope}/{slugZodiac}.{_format}", name="horoscope_detail", defaults={"_format": "html"})
 *
 * @ParamConverter("horoscopeSigne", class="AppBundle:HoroscopeSigne", options={
 *    "mapping": {"slugHoroscope": "slugHoroscope", "slugZodiac": "slugZodiac"},
 *    "repository_method" = "findByComplexSlug",
 *    "map_method_signature" = true
 * })
 */
public function detailAction(HoroscopeSigne $horoscopeSigne)
{

    $this->formMethod();        

     $template = $horoscopeSigne
        ->getHoroscope()
        ->getHoroscopeModele()
        ->getTemplatePath();

    return $this->render('horoscope/'.$template, [
        'horoscope' => $horoscopeSigne->getHoroscope(),
        'horoscopeSigne' => $horoscopeSigne,
    ]);
}

private function formMethod() {
    $form = $this->createForm(DateType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data  = $form->getData();

        dump($data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok thanks ! I will try the second option with a private method :) I just had to use the Symfony Request Object as param of my function and return the form for my View but I think it should works :)

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to pass in parameters and return certain things, looks like a date from your formtype, but it at least reuses code.

Comment: Yeah thanks again, I'm in internship so I will see what the main Developer says about this method but at least I won't have to write the same thing twice :)